# Prolog sorting list using sort method

Tags: list, sorting, lambda, prolog

```
sort([ [30,100], [10,11] ], X).
```

gets

```
X = [[10,11],[30,100]]
```

How can I sort only by the first index of each sublist?

i.e

```
X = [[10,100], [30, 11]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Suppose you have [[10,12],[10,11]]. What would be the desired output? Is [[10,12],[10,11]] ok for output? Are you looking to just change the first elements of the lists based on sorting order and to leave the rest of each list as is?

Comment: Yes, ignore the second index, only sort first of each sublist.

Comment: I am not aware of any standard functions that do this. You may have to code your own custom predicate. The steps would be to store the tails of each list in a new list, keep the heads in a new list, sort the heads list and append both the resulting lists

Comment: Do post your code as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is my untested code.. there may be one/two cosmetic errors...  The input list is split into two based on the head value on the list and the resulted two lists are recursively processed to finally result the sorted output.

```
sort(Input,Output):-sort(Input,[],Output).

sort([],SortedOut,SortedOut).
sort([[Index1,Index2]|Tail],SortedBig,Out):-
    split(Tail,[Index1,Index2],LessList,BigList),
    !,sort(BigList,SortedBig,NewSort),
    sort(LessList,[[Index1,Index2]|NewSort],Out).

split([],[_D],[],[]).
split([[Index1,Index2]|Rem],[Index21,Index22],[[Index1,Index1]|L1],L2):-
    Index1<Index21,
    !,split(Rem,[Index21,Index22],L1,L2).
split([[Index1,Index2]|Rem],[Index21,Index22],L1,[[Index1,Index1]|L2]):-
    !,split(Rem,[Index21,Index22],L1,L2).
```

Try this and let me know...

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way should be perusing the available builtins. Then take the first element from each sublist, sort them, and replace in the original:

```
sortfirst(L, S) :-
    maplist(get_first, L, A),
    msort(A, B),
    maplist(set_first, L, B, S).

get_first([E|_], E).
set_first([_|R], E, [E|R]).
```

**edit**: note that msort is required, to avoid losing duplicates.

test:

```
?- sortfirst([ [30,100], [10,11] ], X).
X = [[10, 100], [30, 11]].
```

get/set first are just needed to adjust the arguments from maplist: if we use [lambda](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl), we can write a true 'one liner' procedure:

```
:- [lambda].

sortfirst_lambda(L, S) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(X = [E|_], Y = E), L, A),
    msort(A, B),
    maplist(\X^Y^Z^(X = [_|R], Y = E, Z = [E|R]), L, B, S).
```

Simple identities can simplify a little that expressions:

```
sortfirst_lambda(L, S) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(X = [Y|_]), L, A),
    msort(A, B),
    maplist(\X^Y^Z^(X = [_|R], Z = [Y|R]), L, B, S).
```

**edit**: or still more simplified:

```
sortfirst_lambda(L, S) :-
    maplist(\[Y|_]^Y^true, L, A),
    msort(A, B),
    maplist(\[_|R]^Y^[Y|R]^true, L, B, S).
```

Here you can see that, as in the original get/set first, just the unification of arguments is needed.

Thus lambda it's syntactically convenient, but has its cost:

```
?- randomlists(100000, 3, -30,+30, L),
 time(sortfirst(L,A)),
 time(sortfirst_lambda(L,B)),
 assertion(A=B).

% 400,012 inferences, 0,482 CPU in 0,483 seconds (100% CPU, 830072 Lips)
% 1,700,012 inferences, 1,717 CPU in 1,721 seconds (100% CPU, 990302 Lips)
L = [[-8, -13, 11], [-13, -27, -29], [5, 10, -24], [-8, -7, -6], [3, -24, -9], [-13, -20, -24], [7, 27|...], [-5|...], [...|...]|...],
A = B, B = [[-30, -13, 11], [-30, -27, -29], [-30, 10, -24], [-30, -7, -6], [-30, -24, -9], [-30, -20, -24], [-30, 27|...], [-30|...], [...|...]|...].
```

here are the service predicates to build sized test data:

```
randomlist(Length, Low, High, List) :-
    findall(E, (between(1, Length, _),
            random(Low, High, E)), List).

randomlists(Length1, Length2, Low, High, ListOfLists) :-
    findall(E, (between(1, Length1, _),
            randomlist(Length2, Low, High, E)), ListOfLists).
```

Answer (score 2):

@chac(+1 btw): there's no need of lambda to one-line this (in swi at least!):

```
sortfirst(L, Res) :-
    maplist(selectchk, X, L, R),
    msort(X, XS),
    maplist(selectchk, XS, Res, R).
```

but lambda versions or your first version are less tricky and more readable I think!